# MVC Charts Date Time on Axis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, charts

I am using chart helper on MVC 5, but I have a problem showing the X labels. The chart and Y label are okay, but I want the X Axis to show the date of each value, right now it shows me for example 1/1/2015 , 1/2/2015,1/3/2015..

But I want it to show for example 12/1/2015, 5/2/2015,9/3/2015.

This is the piece of the code of how I get my data. I use interval=1 on xml chart theme but still not working, I think the solution its define the x type as string but I'm not sure of how to do it.

```
  var myChart=  new System.Web.Helpers.Chart(width: 800, height: 500, theme: coso_theme)
        .AddTitle("Contamination Chart")
            .AddSeries(
                chartType: "Column",
                xValue: monitoreos, xField: "fecha",
                yValues: monitoreos, yFields: "valor");
```

Comment: Show us the code how `monitoreos` is being populated? And yes, if you have `var monitoreos = new[] {"12/1/2015", "5/2/2015", "9/3/2015"}`, it will work for xaxis.

Comment: It comes from database:   IEnumerable<Monitoreo> monitoreos = db.Monitoreos.Where(m => m.metricaID == 7);